# How to use pwntools to generate a relative jump?

Tags: assembly

I want to use [pwntools](https://docs.pwntools.com/en/stable/) to generate a relative jump 0x20 bytes forward. It isn't described in the documentation how to do that.

What's the command for doing a `JMP SHORT 0x20` in pwntools?

Comment: I did a search for "pwntools jump" and found an answer from the developer. I'm not sure this question belongs here when it's so easily found by search and from an official source.

Comment: You probably mean this issue? That's the only reference I can find https://github.com/Gallopsled/pwntools/issues/1287

It comes out pretty poorly in my opinion. That's why I created the question, so people wouldn't have to dig through github issues about pwntools exceptions to arrive at such a simple solution to a very common use case (for binary exploitation)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the syntax for doing relative jumps in pwntools on the command line:

```
pwn asm 'jmp $+0x20'
```

And this is how you can do it in code:

```
>>> import pwn
>>> pwn.asm('jmp $+0x20')
b'\xeb\x1e'
```